# Why are managed css/less assets not processed by sbt-less plugin in Play 2.3?

Tags: playframework, less, sbt, playframework-2.3

I upgraded to play 2.3, and followed the instructions described in [Using LESS CSS](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/AssetsLess) to use the less plugin. However, the less file is not being compiled to css and sent to `target`. The JS files however are working.

All I did was to add the less and jslint plugins as follows:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")
```

File structure:

```
/assets
  /javascripts -> *.js files are linted and staged
  /stylesheets -> *.less files not working
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks! It fixed now.

- Only when `*.scala` full build file is used. Add the following imports to the build:

  ```
  import com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb.autoImport._
  import com.typesafe.sbt.less.Import.LessKeys
  ```
- Add the following to project settings:

  ```
  includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"

  // for minified *.min.css files
  LessKeys.compress := true
  ```

Comment: Setting `LessKeys.compress := true` indeed minimized my css assets. However, now I don't have the uncompressed css anymore. I'd like to have the `.css` AND the `.min.css` files side-by-side is it was in Play <= 2.2

Comment: @anfuerer See [https://github.com/sbt/sbt-less/issues/35](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-less/issues/35)

Comment: Indeed, source maps support makes the non-minified version obsolete. I wasn't aware of the source maps feature the time I wrote the comment above.

Comment: If you're new to this like I am, you need to pass the:
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less" to the settings() function of your project or it won't find all of the less files.

Comment: @JasonD Indeed, without adding `includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"` to `build.sbt` Play would only apply `main.less` to the websites but no `other.less`.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by adding those two lines in build.sbt:

```
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"
excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"
```

Comment: Yep, the same lines are now mentioned in the LESS sections of the Play 2.3 migration doc http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23. Problem with using bleeding-edge technologies are incomplete docs.